# How can I get rid of this table border?

Tags: html

I've tried everything but nothing short of setting the outer-most table's border to 0 works. I want to get rid of the line below the cell with "big cell text" in it. Code is pretty messy but here's the [link to jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wz8Tz/) so you could... fiddle around with it. The code to the table structure is exactly the same as what I use in the site but obviously the data is replaced.

Any clues?

Comment: like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CTZdp/) ?

Comment: @sled no, I want to keep every other border except that one line between "big cell text" and "1: text1...". The post wasn't really clear about that, fixed now.

Comment: ah sorry, then go for PiTheNumber's solution :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set border-bottom and border-top to none: http://jsfiddle.net/nUrE7/

Comment: thanks it works normally but the plugin i'm using can't interpret it

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. Added **border-bottom:none;** and **border-top:none;** in your code.

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="1" style="width: 100%;">
  <tr >
    <td colspan="7" border="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; height: 100px; vertical-align:middle;border-bottom:none;"> big cell text </td>
  </tr>
  <tr border="0">
    <td colspan="7" border="0" style="width: 100%; text-align: left; vertical-align:middle;border-top:none; "><table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="1" border="0" style="width: 100%;">
        <tr border="0">
          <td border="0" width="10%"><strong>1:</strong></td>
          <td border="0" width="90%" style="text-align: left;">text1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr border="0">
          <td border="0" width="10%"><strong>2: </strong></td>
          <td border="0" width="90%" style="text-align: left;">text2</td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr border="0">
    <td colspan="5" style="width: 74%;text-align: right;">Total</td>
    <td style="width: 13%; text-align: right; height: 20px; vertical-align:middle;">a</td>
    <td style="width: 13%; text-align: right; height: 20px; vertical-align:middle;">b</td>
  </tr>
  <tr border="0">
    <td colspan="5" style="width: 74%; vertical-align:middle; text-align: center; height: 20px;"><strong>c</strong></td>
    <td colspan="2" style="width: 26%; text-align: center; height: 20px; vertical-align:middle;">d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```